# Evaluating the integral $S=\int_0^12\pi t^4\sqrt{9t^2+4}dt$

Tags: integration, parametric

I want to find the surface area $S$ by rotating the curve
about the
$x$-axis
   $$ \begin{cases}
        x  = t^3 \\
        y  = t^2
    \end{cases}
    ,t\in [0,1]
    $$
At some point I find $$S=\int_0^12\pi t^4\sqrt{9t^2+4}dt$$ and I can't go further to evaluate this integral. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why do you have $t^4$ in your integrand? Shouldn't it be $t^3$? In which case you substitute $u=9t^2+4$.

Comment: @DavidQuinn $S=\int_0^12\pi t^3\sqrt{9t^4+4t^2}dt$ that's where we get $t^4$ in the integrand : it comes from the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral formula for $S$ is incorret. It should be $$\begin{align}S &= \int_0^1 2\pi t^2 \sqrt{9t^4 + 4t^2} dt = \int_0^1 2\pi t^2 \cdot t \sqrt{9t^2 + 4} dt \\&= 2\pi\int_0^1  \color{red}{t^3} \sqrt{9t^2 + 4} dt\end{align}$$

Now simply take $u = 9t^2 + 4$.

Comment: It's about the $x$-axis not the $y$-axis so if $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$ then $S=\int_0^12\pi f(t)\sqrt{f'(t)^2+g'(t)^2}\;dt$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It's $2\pi g(t)$, isn't? About the x-axis the radius of each "circunference" is $y$.

Comment: I thought it would be $2\pi g(t)$ as you said if it was to rotate the curve about  the $y$-axis .. Am i wrong ?

Comment: Yes, you are. The radius is given by $y$ when rotated by the x-axis.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\text{S}=\int_{0}^{1}2\pi t^4\sqrt{9t^2+4}\space\text{d}t=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}t^4\sqrt{9t^2+4}\space\text{d}t=$$

---

Substitute $t=\frac{2\tan(u)}{3}$ and $\text{d}t=\frac{2\sec^2(u)}{3}\space\text{d}u$.

Then $\sqrt{9t^2+4}=\sqrt{4\tan^2(u)+4}=2\sec(u)$ and $u=\arctan\left(\frac{3t}{2}\right)$.

This gives a new lower bound $u=\arctan\left(\frac{3\cdot0}{2}\right)=0$ and upper bound $u=\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$:

---

$$\frac{128\pi}{243}\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\tan^4(u)\sec^4(u)\space\text{d}u=\frac{128\pi}{243}\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\left[\sec^7(u)-2\sec^5(u)+\sec^3(u)\right]\space\text{d}u$$
$$\frac{128\pi}{243}\left[\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\sec^7(u)\space\text{d}u-2\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\sec^5(u)\space\text{d}u+\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\sec^3(u)\space\text{d}u\right]$$

---

After this:

- start using the reduction formula:
  $$\int\sec^m(u)\space\text{d}u=\frac{\sin(u)\sec^{m-1}(u)}{m-1}+\frac{m-2}{m-1}\int\sec^{m-2}(u)\space\text{d}u$$
- and notice:
  $$\int\sec(u)\space\text{d}u=\ln\left|\tan(u)+\sec(u)\right|+\text{C}$$